# How to update array list using textbox

Tags: arrays, json, algorithm, hyperlink, event-handling

I made a list of arrays using JSON and display it as links. Now, I have textboxes below the lists where the array list item would appear if it was clicked. How would I update the value of the array list item if I changed it on the textbox and clicked on save so that even if the page is refreshed, the new data should appear on the list instead of the old one.

By the way, the codes for the array, displaying the array, the textboxes and buttons are all in the same html page.

Comment: To start with, you can use `JSON.stringify` on the array object and put it in the text box. After manual editing, apply it to the array using `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

> To start with, you can use JSON.stringify on the array object and put it in the text box. After manual editing, apply it to the array using JSON.parse.